# Unity2D hide everything that is outside shape defined by edgecollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D polygon that is defined by a edgeCollider. Is there a way to hide everything that is outside of the shape and show only what is inside?

I tried using skyboxes and lights. I thought about creating a mask(but i dont know how to create such a mask).

Is there a way to only show what is inside the shape defined by edge collider?

Answer (score 2):

What about using the colliders trigger events?
Set this polygon as a trigger in the edgeCollider2D component in the inspector. Then you can use the collider OnEnterTrigger2D.

Your gameobjects are all disabled until this edgeCollider collides with in. Then disable the gameobject OnExitTrigger2D.

If you wanted to limit it to a certain number of object only. You would set a layer to only hide/show these object.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
     if(other.gameObject.layer == "hiddenObject"){
         other.gameObject.enable = true;
     }
}
```

Then the reverse on the OnTriggerExit2D.

I'm not sure the effect that you are aiming for. So another solution could be a postprocessing shader.

I can only give a high level description on this however.

You would take the final screen image texture, and the current position of the polygon and then add the pixels from the screen texture to the polygon texture and output this texture. (this shader has to exists already).

But you want the inverse of these.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-TransparentCutoutFamily.html

You're wanting to keep what's in the hole and get rid of what's outside of it?

You can download the built in shaders to edit them here

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

Just find your version of unity and select builtin shaders from the drop down.

**Edit:**  "SPOTLIGHT!", try this but with your custom shape

http://www.shaderslab.com/demo-49---spotlight.html